# After callback doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is User model, and when user creates account, letter with link for confirmation is sent to his email adress. `after_callback` sets user's `confirmed` column to `false`.
(I don't sure about if more than one callbacks of one type is possible, there are two after callbacks)

User.rb:

```
after_create :confirmation
after_create :add_user_profile
```

...

```
def confirmation
    if self.guest
      self.confirmed=true
    elsif self.authentication
      self.confirmed=true
    else
      self.confirmed=false
      begin
        confirmation_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end while User.exists?(:confirmation_token => confirmation_token)
      self.confirmation_token=confirmation_token
      self.confirmation_link_sent_at=Time.now.utc
      UserMailer.send_confirmation_link(self).deliver
      User.delay.delete_unconfirmed(self)
    end
  end
```

But when I output last user from console:

```
>> User.last
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
#<User id: 21, email: "somddething@mail.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$LMtsumUaS5MaiRhz3.mZ2em7Fbt3.66pbpe4863zj3b0...", created_at: "2013-05-22 17:17:18", updated_at: "2013-05-22 17:17:18", guest: false, auth_token: "lbIJftEqgwyXYymjEVdhCQ", password_reset_token: nil, password_link_sent_at: nil, confirmed: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmation_link_sent_at: nil>
```

As you can see, confirmed is nil, also others related columns too. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not working because your are setting the `confirmed` attribute to the users but you are not saving it again.

Depending on your needs, you can change the callback to `before_create` or save the user:

```
def confirmation
  ...
  self.save
end
```

Hop this helps!

Comment: thanks! Always forget that I need to call save after such things.